# How to offset rows from each other during a While Loop in PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to `offset` the same `columns` of data to each other so I can calculate the difference in time between them.

The data I am selecting from the `DB` looks like the following.

```
22/12/2015 14:01    22/12/2015 14:01
22/12/2015 14:02    22/12/2015 14:02
04/01/2016 07:48    04/01/2016 07:48
04/01/2016 07:48    04/01/2016 07:48
04/01/2016 07:49    04/01/2016 07:49
04/01/2016 07:49    04/01/2016 07:49
04/01/2016 07:49    04/01/2016 07:49
04/01/2016 07:50    04/01/2016 07:50
04/01/2016 08:00    04/01/2016 08:00
04/01/2016 08:18    04/01/2016 08:18
```

I need it to look like this -

```
22/12/2015 14:01    22/12/2015 14:02
22/12/2015 14:02    04/01/2016 07:48
04/01/2016 07:48    04/01/2016 07:48
04/01/2016 07:48    04/01/2016 07:49
04/01/2016 07:49    04/01/2016 07:49
04/01/2016 07:49    04/01/2016 07:49
04/01/2016 07:49    04/01/2016 07:50
04/01/2016 07:50    04/01/2016 08:00
04/01/2016 08:00    04/01/2016 08:18
04/01/2016 08:18    04/01/2016 08:20
```

As you can see, I have simply removed the first row of the second column so that they are now different and then can be calculated to get the difference.

I could easily get around this in my while loop if you could actually access it with Integer keys like so -

```
    $results = CDB::ExecuteQuery($SQL);

            $firstMovementCounter = 0; // Start counter as normal
            $secondMovementCounter = 1; // Start offset to first movement to calculate difference between movements.
            while ($rows = CDB::GetAssoc($results))                    
            {
                $differenceInSeconds = $rows["FIRST_MOVEMENT"][$firstMovementCounter] - $rows["SECOND_MOVEMENT"][$secondMovementCounter];  

$firstMovementCounter++;
$secondMovementCounter++;

            }
```

But this doesn't seem to work. Is there another way of succeeding with this method ?

To delve deeper, I put it into debug and seen that on the first loop of the results the $rows variable was = to the following -

```
array(2) (
  [FIRST_MOVEMENT] => (string) 2015-12-22 14:01:15
  [SECOND_MOVEMENT] => (string) 2015-12-22 14:01:15
)
```

And that `$rows["FIRST_MOVEMENT"][$firstMovementCounter]` was = to `1`

Which makes no sense

Another way would be to be able to ignore the `first row` of the right hand `column`, without skipping the `first row` in the first `column`. But I can't see any easy way around this.

Could any one shed some light on what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try below code:

```
$results = CDB::ExecuteQuery($SQL);

$firstMovementCounter = 0;
$secondMovementCounter = 1;
while ($rows = CDB::GetAssoc($results))                    
{
    $allrows[] = $rows;
}

for($i = 0; $i < count($allrows); $i++) {
    $differenceInSeconds = $allrows[$firstMovementCounter]['FIRST_MOVEMENT'] - $allrows[$secondMovementCounter]['SECOND_MOVEMENT'];
    $firstMovementCounter++;
    $secondMovementCounter++;
}
```

Here for the last array key you have to add condition.

Comment: Sorry, this is how my code is, I retyped it and made a stupid typo!

Comment: I am saying my code is like your answer, but it doesn't give the required result

Comment: $rows["FIRST_MOVEMENT"][$firstMovementCounter] returns the value of 1 and on the next loop it returns "-"

Comment: What is your $rows array ?

Comment: array(2) (
      [FIRST_MOVEMENT] => (string) 2015-12-22 14:01:15
      [SECOND_MOVEMENT] => (string) 2015-12-22 14:01:15
    )

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered doing this in the database? In MySQL for example you could query the same table twice and pull out the date field twice.

```
SELECT
    A.requestid,
    A.dateime AS starttime,
    B.dateime AS endtime
FROM
    MyTable A
INNER JOIN
    MyTable B ON B.requestid = (A.requestid + 1)
ORDER BY
    A.requestid ASC
```

This could give you the result set you are looking for with no need to process the result in PHP

```
+-----------+------------------+------------------+
| requestid | starttime        | endtime          |
+-----------+------------------+------------------+
| 1         | 22/12/2015 14:01 | 22/12/2015 14:02 |
| 2         | 22/12/2015 14:02 | 04/01/2016 07:48 |
| 3         | 04/01/2016 07:48 | 04/01/2016 07:48 |
| 4         | 04/01/2016 07:48 | 04/01/2016 07:49 |
| 5         | 04/01/2016 07:49 | 04/01/2016 07:49 |
| 6         | 04/01/2016 07:49 | 04/01/2016 07:49 |
| 7         | 04/01/2016 07:49 | 04/01/2016 07:50 |
| 8         | 04/01/2016 07:50 | 04/01/2016 08:00 |
| 9         | 04/01/2016 08:00 | 04/01/2016 08:18 |
| 10        | 04/01/2016 08:18 | 04/01/2016 08:20 |
+-----------+------------------+------------------+
```